# Send a POST request via intent

Tags: java, android, post, android-intent

I need to send a POST request to another application, via intent. I tried the following code but it only makes a GET request. I don't know how I can pass the POST parameters.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
intent.setPackage("app.package.name");    
PackageManager packageManager = requireActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) == null) {
  //do something
}
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to send a POST request to another application, via intent

If you wrote the other application, you can create your own protocol for passing the rest of the details, such as via `Intent` extras.

If you did not write the other application, then most likely you have no ability to force it to do a `POST` request. You would have to read the documentation for that other application — if any documentation exists — to see what sort of `Intent`-based API it exposes.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not written the other application, I have documentation about it.